# Display a single object in layout from JSON

Tags: android, android-layout, android-volley

I feel silly asking this, but how do I display a single object in an android layout after obtaining it's data from JSON? I know how to display data in a listview, but haven't learned how to display a single object. Do I need any kind of adapter?

Here's how I parse the data from Volley (I'm aware of libraries like Jackson and GSON):

```
public void parseDeal(JSONObject response) {

    Deal dealItem = new Deal();

    try {

        dealItem.setId(response.getInt("id"));

        dealItem.setHeadline(response.getString("headline"));

        dealItem.setTimeStamp(response.getString("created_at"));

        dealItem.setImge(response.getString("image_url"));

        JSONObject mVendor = response.getJSONObject("vendor");

        dealItem.setVendorPic(mVendor.getString("image_url"));

        // how to adapt to the view?

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There are certain JSON attributes in the object that may come back null, so I want to be able to handle those by changing their visibility in the view conditionally. I have done that in a list adapter before like this, but not sure if I need an adapter in this case:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getHeadline())) {
            headlineMsg.setText(item.getHeadline());
            headlineMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            headlineMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my Deal object class.

```
public class Deal {
    private int id;
    private String headline, image, vendorPic, timeStamp;

    public Deal() {
    }

    public Deal(int id, String image, String headline,
            String vendorPic, String timeStamp) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.image = image;
        this.headline = headline;
        this.vendorPic = vendorPic;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImge() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImge(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getHeadline() {
        return headline;
    }

    public void setHeadline(String headline) {
        this.headline = headline;
    }

    public String getVendorPic() {
        return vendorPic;
    }

    public void setVendorPic(String vendorPic) {
        this.vendorPic = vendorPic;
    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have getters in the dealItem object? or can you share the dealItem class too?

Comment: Yes, sure do. I can post that if you'd like.

Comment: If you could do that i can help you out !

Comment: Updated with data class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i can follow you're logic here. You should work on implementing a rendering class. This is called upon the loading of the visual component that holds all this information. The renderer should turn on and off the views that are not null. The rendering class is the actual code that takes the data you have pulled out of the json, checks it to make sure there is data actually there (not null) and sets the required view to the desired value.

`if (dealItem.getTimeStamp() != null && dealItem.getTimeStamp() != "") {
            LayoutView.setText(dealItem.getTimeStamp()));
            LayoutView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            LayoutView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}`

Comment: So I don't even really need my `Deal` class?

Comment: Sure you do, it's a good practice to have POJO classes on your project.

Comment: The point of having the deal class is that it is a local representation of the object that you are receiving. Each time you receive a deal you should use the data to create an object item. This means that you will be able to manipulate the data, retrieve information from it sort it into lists perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply create a Fragment or activity with TextViews (or whatever view you prefer...) ?

You don't need an adapter for that. Then you simply populate it on onCreate (activity) or fragment (onViewCreated) with the values from the object !

Hope it helps !

Comment: Haha, that is exactly what I want to do. I'm an android greenhorn and haven't had the chance to dig into fragments yet. An activity with TextViews is sort of what I'm shooting for. The question for me is: how do I do that for a single object? As I said, I'm familiar with listviews and adapters. I imagine that a single object should be easier.

Comment: Simply create a xml with your layout, arranging the textviews as you like and bind it all together on onCreate of your activity. Gonna edit my answer to clarify!